# d3 update pattern of nested data model

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been  struggling to deal with a problem of updating a nested data in d3, the code:

```
var data = [
  {key: 1, values:[1, 2, 3]},
  {key: 2, values:[3, 4, 5]},
 ] 
function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#gogo')
  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)

  tr.enter().append('tr')

  var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(d=>d.values )
    .text(d=>d)

  td.enter().append('td')
    .text(d=>d)
}
update(data)
ref()
function ref() {
  setInterval(()=>{
    data.map(item=> {
      for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        item.values[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
      }
    })
    update(data)
  }, 1000)
}
```

The problem of above code is d3 doesn't render the first run of update(data), if comment out the ref() function, d3 just doesn't append the new data into html.

Comment: I don't see any issue in updating data in **the first run**. It works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7wpf1e52/ If this isn't what you're looking for, could you please elaborate a bit more on the issue?

Comment: May I ask your version of d3? I'm using the latest one(d3 v5.1).  Does the problem related to the d3 version?:

Comment: My bad. I should've asked the d3 version you were using. I used d3 v3 and it worked fine. Anyway, I'll post the solution for v4/v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this might be a repetitive issue to answer but I still think it might be useful to a lot of developers who are new to d3. Also, the **blog** that I refer to here, is really very useful.

To overcome the usability issue from d3 v3, a new selection class `merge` was introduced.

Mark's words:

> D3 4.0 removes the magic of enter.append. (In fact, D3 4.0 removes the distinction between enter and normal selections entirely: there is now only one class of selection.) In its place, a new selection.merge method can unify the enter and update selections:

You can read more on this here: [d3 CHANGES#selection](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#user-content-selections-d3-selection)

Also, I came across this blog which I'd like to share: https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488

In your example, using the same `merge` logic, here's the snippet:

```js
var data = [
  {key: 1, values:[1, 2, 3]},
  {key: 2, values:[3, 4, 5]},
 ] 
function update(data) {
  var table = d3.select('#gogo')
  var tr = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data)

  var rowenter = tr.enter().append('tr')

  var td = tr.merge(rowenter).selectAll("td span")
    .data(d=>d.values )
    .text(d=>d)

  td.enter().append('td').append('span')
    .text(d=>d)
}
update(data)
ref()
function ref() {
  setInterval(()=>{
    data.map(item=> {
      for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        item.values[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1
      }
    })
    update(data)
  }, 1000)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<table id="gogo">

</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Shashank, Now I'm trying to wrap a <span></span> inside td, still can't figure out how to do it, would you please give me a hint?

Comment: Edited the post snippet to wrap the text in a `span`.